# How to make Bitcoin-Qt or other client run off of a flash drive (Mac)

Tags: client, portable

I work in an office with lots of computers, and I am on a different workstation every day. Is there a bitcoin client I can keep on a FireWire/USB drive?

Bitcoin-Qt on Mac leaves all the files in the home directory - the block chain, the wallet, etc. Someone else is going to be using this computer tomorrow! I want to keep all those files, and even the application itself, on a portable drive.

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 7):

[Somebody posted a portable client](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=18870.0), but I don't trust them, so I'll show you how to make your own.

### Windows guide

1. Download the windows .zip from [bitcoin.org](http://bitcoin.org/en/download)
2. Unpack it. Go into that directory.
3. Make a file called `launch.txt`
   Put this in it:

   ```
    start bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir=data
   ```
4. Rename it to `launch.bat`
5. Make a folder called `data`

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv5UM.jpg). Double-click `launch.bat` to start it. If files show up in the data folder you made, then you've done things correctly.

### Macintosh guide

Download the Mac .dmg from [bitcoin.org](http://bitcoin.org/en/download)

Find the Bitcoin-Qt.app file, and copy it to to your flash drive.

Go to Launchpad, type in 'terminal'. Hit enter.

When the terminal comes up, type:

```
cd /path/to/flash/drive
mkdir data
cd Bitcoin-Qt.app/Content/MacOS
nano start.sh; chmod +x start.sh
```

Type in:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
dir=`echo $dir1 | sed 's/"/\\"/g' | tr -d '\n'`
data="$dir/../../data"
"$dir"/bitcoin -datadir="$data"
```

Now hit Ctrl-O, enter, Ctrl-X. You should be back at the terminal.

```
cd ..
nano Info.plist
```

Find the lines that look like this:

```
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Bitcoin-Qt</string>
```

Change it to:

```
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>start.sh</string>
```

Now hit Ctrl-O, enter, Ctrl-X. You should be back at the terminal. Now we just need to give it a better name.

```
cd ../..
mv Bitcoin-Qt.app BitcoinPortable.app
```

Try running your BitcoinPortable.app. If you see files show up in the data directory next to it, then you've done things correctly!

[Thanks to Pygy for the script](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=16258.0)
*Note: I don't have a Mac, so this is untested.*

Comment: `cd Bitcoin-Qt.app/Content/Resources
cd ../MacOS` why not just `cd Bitcoin-Qt.app/Content/MacOS`?

Comment: Works for Dogecoin too. Had to point the installer to the external drive and then follow your instructions (on Windows). Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. After the 'nano Info.plist' it creates a new file, so it's not possible to change those lines...

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on MAC OS 10.6.8 with Bitcoin-Qt 0.8.1-beta.
I'm combining and editing the [Pygmy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733824/how-to-run-a-sh-script-in-an-unix-console-mac-terminal) and Nick ODells answer, there were a few typos.

Also note, I opened the application with right-click >> "Show Package Contents" and then edited the files with the finder, and TextWrangler. No Terminal required!

1) Create new directory in `Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/Resources` and name it `data`

2) Navigate up a level and then open the MacOS folder

3) In that folder, create a new file called `start.sh`

4) open that new file in a text editor and write:

```
#! /bin/sh
dir1=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
dir=`echo $dir1 | sed 's/"/\\"/g' | tr -d '\n'`
data="$dir/../Resources/data"
"$dir"/Bitcoin-Qt -datadir="$data"
```

note that the last line contains the name of the only other file in the MacOS folder (Bitcoin-Qt). That's important! Because that is the program that will be executed a the end of the script you just wrote. Also, that fourth line has to link to the 'data' folder we created in step #1

5) Navigate back up a level to `Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/` and open the file called `Info.plist`

6) Find the lines that look like this:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>Bitcoin-Qt</string>
```

Change it to:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>start.sh</string>
```